# References for representations of Heisenberg Lie algebra

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Please suggest some reference material for the representations of the infinite dimensional Heisenberg Lie Algebra or the oscillator algebra. I already looked at Kac and Rainas book, any other reference will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

"Finite and infinite dimensional Lie algebras and applications in Physics" by     G.G.A. Bäuerle and E.A. de Kerf.